# Texture Paint multiple Objects in Blender 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

In 2.8, there's a new feature to edit multiple objects.

I can also unwarp multiple objects in the UV editor. Everything works great but I can't find a way to texture-paint multiple objects at the same time.

Does this feature exist or is it planned in the future?

Thanks

Comment: This feature doesn't exist at the moment. You can still paint one object at a time and easily switch between them, if brush settings are your concern.

Comment: the problem is i use 'left click' selection so to switch to other object by default is to use 'alt left'  but .... i already bind the alt left for other function. So i was trying to find out what is the command in keymap to re-assign hotkey and couldn't find it. Do you know ?

Comment: I haven't changed much in the keymap config, because as an old Blender user I still prefer right-click.